# How to get the pointer address of a ctypes.c_char_p instance

Tags: python, ctypes

I want to extract the integer address that a `ctypes.c_char_p` instance points to.

For example, in

```
>>> import ctypes
>>> s = ctypes.c_char_p("hello")
>>> s
c_char_p(4333430692)
```

the value I'd like to fetch is **4333430692** — the address of the string `hello\0` in memory:

```
(lldb) x 4333430692
0x1024ae7a4: 68 65 6c 6c 6f 00 5f 70 00 00 00 00 05 00 00 00  hello._p........
```

I've read the ctypes docs, but there doesn't seem to be any way of doing that. The closest is `ctypes.addressof`, but that only gives me the location of the pointer, of course.

The reason why I want this is because I'm calling some C functions that actually expects raw addresses encoded as integers (whose size equals the native pointer width).

Comment: The function prototype may use `intptr_t` or `int64_t`, but that doesn't prevent you from using `c_char_p` in ctypes. A `char *` pointer is passed as an integer address.

Comment: Sure, but the use case for me is a bit different: I'm JITing code and need to pass the address to an intermediate Python function that expects integers, which then assembles a call to a C function. I failed to mention that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could just cast it to `c_void_p` and get the value:

```
>>> ctypes.cast(s, ctypes.c_void_p).value
4333430692
```

Comment: Alternatively, use the buffer protocol: `ctypes.c_void_p.from_buffer(s).value`. Using `from_buffer` is about 3 times faster since `cast` is implemented using an FFI call. But for the difference to matter you'd have to be doing this millions of times in a tight loop that does nothing else.